# Responding with a stream sometimes result in "Connection reset by peer" error

Tags: scala, http, stream, akka, akka-http

In our application we have routes that are streaming JSON documents. Here is an example:

```
/** GET api/1/tenant/(tenantId)/ads/ */
def getAllAdsByOwner(advertiserId: AdvertiserId): Route =
  get {
    httpRequiredSession { username =>
      getAllTenantAds(username, advertiserId) { (adSource: Source[AdView, Any]) =>
        complete(adSource)
      }
    }
  }
```

Most of the time it works as expected, but sometimes, especially when there are many simultaneous requests, the server starts resetting connection just after the headers have been sent.
I tested with a script that requests this route with curl in a loop and aborting if the request failed. It was running for about 2 minutes before stopping. Trace when request fails is the following:

```
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 54 bytes (0x36)
0000: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://<...>
<= Recv header, 135 bytes (0x87)
0000: Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, Refr
0040: esh-Token, Set-Authorization, Set-Refresh-Token, asset-content-l
0080: ength
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
<= Recv header, 24 bytes (0x18)
0000: Content-Encoding: gzip
<= Recv header, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: X-Frame-Options: DENY
<= Recv header, 33 bytes (0x21)
0000: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: Content-Security-Policy: .
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: default-src 'self';.
<= Recv header, 63 bytes (0x3f)
0000: style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.googleapis.com;.
<= Recv header, 59 bytes (0x3b)
0000: font-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://fonts.gstatic.com;.
<= Recv header, 99 bytes (0x63)
0000: script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://*.google
0040: apis.com https://maps.gstatic.com;.
<= Recv header, 69 bytes (0x45)
0000: img-src 'self' data: https://*.googleapis.com https://*.gstatic.
0040: com;.
<= Recv header, 8 bytes (0x8)
0000:
<= Recv header, 26 bytes (0x1a)
0000: Server: akka-http/10.1.3
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Wed, 27 Jun 2018 15:20:24 GMT
<= Recv header, 28 bytes (0x1c)
0000: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<= Recv header, 32 bytes (0x20)
0000: Content-Type: application/json
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000:
== Info: Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
== Info: stopped the pause stream!
== Info: Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

The same request inspected in Wireshark:

[screen shot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1911270/42023670-7eeccf70-7ad1-11e8-8c49-dfcc4cd10cc1.png)

Reading logs didn't give any hint about probable source of the problem. Response logged as successful:

```
[27-06-2018 19:44:52.837][INFO] access: 'GET /api/1/tenant/ca764a91-8616-409c-8f08-c64a40d3fc07/ads' 200 596ms
```

Versions of used software:

- Scala: 2.11.11
- akka: 2.5.13
- akka-http: 10.1.3

Configuration:

- [akka.conf](https://pastebin.com/raw/57PvCPb5)
- [akka-http-core.conf](https://pastebin.com/raw/3TkTvaka)

I tried increasing `akka.http.host-connection-pool.max-connections` to 128 but it didn't help. Maybe someone has an idea if this is a bug in akka-http or configuration problem?

Comment: Are you creating a new `Route` for each `Connection` or `Request`?  If so, have you tried a single Route to facilitate all Requests?

Comment: FYI Ilya opened an issue for this with akka-http: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/2093

Answer (score 4):

If there is no I/O on your open connection for the idle-timeout, Akka will close the connection which often appears as a "connection reset by peer" error.  Try increasing the akka.http.server.idle-timeout value.

Because your akka.http.server.request-timeout value is the same as akka.http.server.idle-timeout, it is a race condition between which timeout will occur first when there is no I/O.  Sometimes, you will see a 503; other times, you will experience a connection reset error.